# How can I mix absolute and relative sizes?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-relativelayout

I want to create a custom list item. Basically it should 3 areas in a horizontal `LinearLayout`. The most left one is supposed to be 50dp wide, the right most one as well. I would like the one in the middle to take up the rest of the space. In the end it should be 50px | width - 100px | 50px.

Can I do this in XML?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:gravity="right" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="0">
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:gravity="fill"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_weight="0">

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0" >

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the `layout-weight` of the middle item to 1. And `layout_width` to `fill_parent`.

Comment: I feel a little stupid now. I could have sworn that I tried to do that - but you probably now that feeling. Can you point me to some more detailed documentation than http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html? Explain the logic of the weights a little further? Thanks!

Comment: An item first takes a certain amount of space. Then, if there is still space left, the remainder is distributed over the diffent parts, based on their weights. So, weight 0 gets nothing extra, weight 2 gets twice the extra space as weight 1, etc. At least, that's the logic of LinearLayout.

Comment: This answer got me to 1000 :-)